# statmodels OLS giving a TypeError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to fit a set of features to statsmodel's OLS linear regression model.

I am adding a few features at a time. With the first two features, it works fine. But when I keep adding new features it gives me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_xml.py", line 337, in <module>
    model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
...
  File "D:\pythonprojects\testproj\test_env\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 132, in _handle_constant
    if not np.isfinite(ptp_).all():
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

So I changed the type of input using

```
X = X.astype(float)
```

Then a different error pops out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_xml.py", line 339, in <module>
    print(model.summary())
...
File "D:\pythonprojects\testproj\test_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1824, in sf
    place(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

My code looks like this.

```
new_df0 = pd.concat([df_lex[0], summary_df[0]], axis = 0, join = 'inner')
new_df1 = pd.concat([df_lex[1], summary_df[1]], axis = 0, join = 'inner')
data = pd.concat([new_df0, new_df1], axis = 1)
print(data.shape)
X = data.values[0:6,:]
Y = data.values[6,:]
Y = Y.reshape(1,88)
X = X.T
Y = Y.T
X = X.astype(float)
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
print(model.summary())
```

First error triggered in `model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()`
Second error triggered in `model.summary()`

But with some other features, there are no errors.

```
new_df0 = pd.concat([df_len[0], summary_df[0]], axis = 0, join = 'inner')
new_df1 = pd.concat([df_len[1], summary_df[1]], axis = 0, join = 'inner')

data = pd.concat([new_df0, new_df1], axis = 1)
print(data.shape)
X = data.values[0:2,:]
Y = data.values[2,:]
Y = Y.reshape(1,88)
X = X.T
Y = Y.T
X = X.astype(float)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
print(model.summary())
```

It looks like when I have only two features it works. But when different 6 features added, it gives the errors. My major concern is to understand the error. Because I have read similar question related to plots in python. But this is triggered in the built-in functions, not in my code. Any suggestions to debug is highly appreciated.

Comment: One thought...what does `data.dtypes` show?  It looks like something that is not an array like object is getting passed to the `np.isinstance` and/or `np.isnan` functions.

Comment: I found a solution when I let one of my friend to look into my code. I was only considering X as input, forgetting Y at all. Y was just 1/0. Then he proposed to set Y also to `astype(float)` and it model is working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the type of `X_opt` and `y`. Probably it's float64, because of computational precision. So, try:

```
X_opt = X_opt.astype(np.float64)
y = y.astype(np.float64)
```

I had been the same error and fixed it in this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
Y.astype(float)
```

did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
model=sm.OLS(df.Y,df.X, missing='drop').fit()
```

It looks like there is a nan value in some variable. By default missing is none and this *might* be the cause.

Comment: It still gives me the same error `'isnan'` at `model.summary()`. So I wonder this is something related to the output of the  `sm.OLS(...)` due to some of my input values are NaNs.

Comment: Assuming I have NaNs in my input feature dataframe I used this `df_lex[i].replace([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan], x)` to replace with `x` where `x`  substituted with 0, 0.0001 (small value). Still the same error.